Does the WPF Renderer limit control inputs per second?
So I'm trying to create a tool which let's me practice my clicks. The idea is to simulate a RuneScape inventory and I want to be able to practice 6 clicks per .6 seconds.
But I've noticed that it doesn't fully register all my clicks, if I click too fast it seems to skip a click or two, and I believe it's because the WPF has some limits in terms of this but I'm not sure.
I'm getting this if I click too fast.
Slot clicked: 1
Recent clicks count: 1
Slot clicked: 5
Recent clicks count: 2
Slot clicked: 6
Recent clicks count: 3
Timer elapsed, clearing recent clicks

But if I slow down my clicks just a tad bit, it seems to work.
I don't think this is a hardware issue.
Does the WPF renderer have a limit and if so, is it possible to bypass this?
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="RSwitch.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RSwitch"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:RSwitch.MVVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="737" Width="517">
    
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InventorySlots}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="7" Columns="4"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.InventorySlotClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<int> _recentClicks;
    private readonly int nWay = 4;

    public ObservableCollection<int> InventorySlots { get; set; }
    public ICommand InventorySlotClickCommand { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InventorySlots = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 28));
        _recentClicks = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600) // 0.6 seconds
        };
        _timer.Tick += OnTimerElapsed;

        InventorySlotClickCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(OnInventorySlotClick);
    }

    private void OnInventorySlotClick(int slot)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Slot clicked: {slot}");
        _recentClicks.Add(slot);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Recent clicks count: {_recentClicks.Count}");
        if (_recentClicks.Count >= nWay)
        {
            Handle8WaySwitch(nWay);
            _recentClicks.Clear();
            _timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!_timer.IsEnabled)
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Timer elapsed, clearing recent clicks");
        _recentClicks.Clear();
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void Handle8WaySwitch(int n)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{n}-way switch completed!");
    }
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}


What is expected output? The problem is not quite clear. The Debug.WriteLine implies you haven't tried Release configuration to rule out debugger overhead? WPF is not game engine, nor it's optimized for high APS inputs (proparaging routed events are expected to slow down input). You may need to give up on commands and events and organize the loop yourself (mouse hook?)

DId you expect one click for each slot?

@JonasH exactly, I clicked 1, 5, 2 6 but it missed 2.

You could try attaching an event handler to the MouseDown event of the window, or use the static Mouse.MouseDown event and see if that makes any difference. Mouse moves can be coalesed, but I would not expect clicks to do so. So your observed behavior seem a bit weird. I would have expected clicks to be queued, up to some fairly large limit.

The "shortest path" is  not MVVM.
